# The type arguments for method Queryable.OrderBy cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I am try to create a common extension method which sorts list of object by a specific property. I am getting the below error for my code.
The type arguments for method Queryable.OrderBy cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I tried to find the answer here could not find any suitable answer.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
  string property)
{
  return list.AsQueryable().OrderBy(property);
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here.

Answer (score 16):

For me adding the following using directive resolved it.

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
```

Comment: It works for `OderBy` but not `OrderByDescending`, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `property string name sort data` then you can use `System.Linq.Dynamic` : [Github Link](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic)

Notice : you have to call `AsQueryable` because Linq.Dynamic only support `IQueryable` Type.

#### Example :

```
void Main()
{
    var datas = new[] { new { id = 3 }, new { id = 2 } };
    var result = datas.OrderByProperty("id");
    Console.WriteLine(result); //2,3
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list,string property)
    {
        return list.AsQueryable().OrderBy(property);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding "using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;" fixed this for me.

Answer (score -1):

`OrderBy` accepts `Func<TSource,TKey>` as argument, not `string`: [Enumerable.OrderBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8)

I don't see any reason why you would simplify something that is simple enough:

```
someEnumerable.OrderBy(item => item.Property);
```

Passing property by `string` would also require reflection to come into play, so it is really discouraged.

Comment: Note that for `IQueryable<T>`, the OP probably wants an `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` rather than a `Func<TSource, TKey>`.